# Signing up for Ubuntu One

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-one

In the Ubuntu One sign-up process, when it gets to the Captcha entry, the phrase "type these above" blocks the letters to be typed so I can't type them correctly.

Comment: What browser are you using, and do you have any ad/script blockers extensions installed?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu One service has been discontinued for some time, and is no longer available for use.  Registering for the service may simply register you for Single Sign On, but will not enable Ubuntu One.